# Windows 10 (Windows Universal App): BluetoothLE heart Rate monitor doesn't connect after first pairing

Tags: c#, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-10-universal

I'm working on a Windows Universal App that communicates with BluetoothLE heart rate monitors.  As of yesterday (related to a windows update, I'm thinking), things appear to be suddenly broken.

Specifically:

- When I first pair a HRM device to my computer (in windows settings, not through their API), my app sees the device just fine, and can subscribe to notifications from the GATT Heart Rate Service (through a method close to the code [here, in the C# sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bluetooth-Generic-5a99ef95).)
- In all subsequent connection attempts, the app will detect the device normally, and indicate that it is paired to windows, but the HRM in question has a `Device.ConnectionStatus` of `BluetoothConnectionStatus.Disconnected`, and never reports hear rate updates.

If you run the MSDN sample above, you'll see the same thing, even though it's a Windows 8/8.1 sample.

This leaves me in a really sticky spot - I *need* to be able to communicate with these devices, but as of right now, it appears that I can only do so consistently unpairing the device from windows, and repairing it.  That is obviously not acceptable.

I've found a few articles that seem to be tangentially related, but none seem to have found a solution.  Help!

Comment: Could you specify what HRM you are using (Make and Model)?

Comment: I'm using a [Scoshe Rhythm+](http://www.scosche.com/rhythm-plus-1).  Incidentally, I have a number of these that I bought over time, and it appears that the issue I outlined above might only be present on the oldest ones.  I suppose it's possible that this is a firmware bug?

Comment: Found the same issue with another Scosche device tonight. Any guesses what I might be doing wrong, @kpathakota?

Comment: have the same problem. Do you fix this?